# Access VBA: Me Keyword in Public Procedure's Optional Argument Default Value?

Tags: vba, ms-access, this, keyword

Can one use the `Me` keyword in defining the default value of an optional argument to a public procedure, in VBA?  An hour or two of Googling around yields no guidance.

Several parameter / search forms exist in an Access front end.  Each of these forms has a combo or list box (cboTargetForm) to specify another form as the target form.  Identical code in each of the forms' code-behind modules assigns the value of this control to a string variable thusly:

`strTargetForm = Me.cboTargetForm`

`Me` in a code-behind module poses no difficulty, of course, but now, the objective is to refactor these modules' redundant code into a single public procedure in a standard module.  The value of this control obviously must be passed to the public procedure as a parameter.  At the same time the control name is identical on each form, so an optional argument with a default value makes great sense.

The current thinking is to define the public function as something like one of:

`Sub UpdateTargetForm(strString As String, Optional strTargetForm As String = Me.cboTargetForm)`

`Sub UpdateTargetForm(strString As String, Optional frmMe As Access.Form = Me)`

Or, perhaps, any of the above while quoting the identifiers containing `Me`.

**The question** is whether any of these or something like them is valid.

Comment: `Me` is not valid in a standard module.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Me is shorthand reference for form or report name that code is behind. Use form reference in a general module `Forms!formname.cboTargetForm`. But you want the form name to be dynamic. That gets tricky.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a default value for an `Optional` parameter in a VBA procedure, you must give it a constant.  Since [Me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword) is not a constant, it can not be used in that situation.

If you want a procedure in a standard module to reference an open form, regardless of whether or not the form instance is passed as the parameter, see whether [Screen.ActiveForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.screen.activeform) is satisfactory.

```
Public Sub MyProcedure(Optional varFrm As Variant)
    Dim frmTarget As Form
    If IsMissing(varFrm) Then
        Set frmTarget = Screen.ActiveForm
    Else
        Set frmTarget = varFrm
    End If
    Debug.Print frmTarget.Name
End Sub
```

Also see [Screen.ActiveControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.screen.activecontrol) in case that's more useful in your intended application.

Comment: `Screen.ActiveForm` is the solution.  I had been thinking along the lines of passing the form instance, as you suggest, but all I really need is a temporary reference to it and one of its controls.  That's about all a standard module can manage, in any event.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The answer simply is that `Me` refers to the current instance of an object and is invalid in a standard module because the latter can't be instantiated.  `Me` can be used in a class module, of course, with the caveat that it refers to the current instance of that class, not of any other objects that may have been passed to the class.

The workaround in this case is to use Screen.ActiveForm in the standard module's code, as others have suggested.  This probably is a separate pointer but it goes out of scope fairly soon.